# @if state in sass with or condtion

Tags: sass

Is it possible to do something like this is sass

```
if(x == y || x == z) {
stuff
}
```

I tried this

```
@if padding-l == x || padding-r == x{
    padding: 0;
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: It looks like it uses "and", "or", and "not". http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#boolean_operations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$padding-l: y;
$padding-r: x;

h1 {
  @if $padding-l == x or $padding-r == x {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```